# Finding minimum time to complete actions that can be done in any order

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

> Lets say you are given `T` (<= 20) tasks. Each task takes a corresponding length of time to complete. After completing
>   each task, you obtain a tool that can be used on specified tasks to
>   complete them `s` :   (0 <= s <= 15) times faster — If a task previously took time t_i,
>   it now takes time `ceil(t_i / s)`. What is the minimum time it takes
>   to complete all the tasks? Note that you can only use one tool at a time for each task — You cannot switch tools in the middle of a task nor can you use multiple tools at the same time.

---

> For instance, say you have to complete 3 tasks.
>
> Task #1 takes 5 minutes. Upon completing you will get a tool that can
>   finish task #2 three times faster and task #3 two times faster.
>
> Task #2 takes 10 minutes. Upon completing you will get a tool that can
>   finish task #1 two times faster and task #3 five times faster.
>
> Task #3 takes 5 minutes. Upon completing you will get a tool that can
>   finish task #1 two times faster and task #2 two times faster.

---

> In this example, the quickest way to proceed is to first complete task #1, use the tool from task #1 to complete task #2 in ceil(10/3) minutes, then use the tool from task #2 to complete task #3 in
>   ceil(5/5) minutes. This leads to a total of 5 + 4 + 1 = 10 minutes.

One way I thought of doing this was recursion). The total time taken is :

```
ceil(curTask/bestTool) + min({otherTasks})
```

where otherTasks is the not-yet completed tasks. Along the way you update the best possible tool for each task.

However, this naive brute-force obviously takes too long. I looked at trying to convert this into a memoized recursion (DP - dynamic programming) but am not sure which values to cache.

The other possible way that might work is to create some sort of graph and run a shortest path algorithm like dijkstra's, but I think just creating the graph itself will have too large of a complexity.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic programming, memoize by cumulative time, tasks left, and time multipliers for each task.

Some sample Python code (if tools are thrown away after each task):

```python
from math import ceil

taskTimes = {1:5, 2:10, 3:5}
tools = {1:(1,3,2), 2:(2,1,5), 3:(2,2,1)}

cache= {}

def rec(totalTime, tasksLeft, multipliers):
    if len(tasksLeft) == 0:
        return totalTime

    key = (totalTime, tasksLeft, multipliers)
    if key in cache: return cache[key]

    t = 10**10
    for task in tasksLeft:
        newTasksLeft = tuple(i for i in tasksLeft if i!=task)
        curTime = ceil(taskTimes[task] / float(multipliers[task-1]))
        t = min(t, rec(totalTime+curTime, newTasksLeft, tools[task]))
    cache[key] = int(t)
    return cache[key]


print rec(0, tuple(range(1,len(tools)+1)), tuple([1]*len(tools)))'
```

If the best tools are kept over time:

```python
from math import ceil

taskTimes = {1:5, 2:10, 3:5}
tools = {1:(1,3,2), 2:(2,1,5), 3:(2,2,1)}


cache= {}

def rec(totalTime, tasksLeft, multipliers):
    if len(tasksLeft) == 0:
        return totalTime

    key = (totalTime, tasksLeft, multipliers)
    if key in cache: return cache[key]

    t = 10**10
    for task in tasksLeft:
        newTasksLeft = tuple(i for i in tasksLeft if i!=task)
        newMultipliers = tuple(max(a,b) for a,b in zip(tools[task], multipliers))
        curTime = ceil(taskTimes[task] / float(multipliers[task-1]))
        t = min(t, rec(totalTime+curTime, newTasksLeft, newMultipliers))
    cache[key] = int(t)
    return cache[key]


print rec(0,tuple(range(1,len(tools)+1)),tuple([1]*len(tools)))
```

Comment: But if you memoize by cumulative time I don't see how you can utilize the memoized value later on. And how would you account for time multipliers that have not been reached yet (tasks that have not been completed?

Comment: Even in the best case, isn't the running time of this exponential?

Comment: I have a clarification question: Are all tools "thrown away" after even task, or do you "keep" tools as you go?

Comment: Anyways, no, the running time wouldn't be exponential because each subtree would only need to be calculated once.

Comment: You can keep the tools as you go but you cannot stack them.